# When does the normal bundle of a submanifold of Euclidean space admit a flat connection?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology

Given a smooth submanifold of $R^n$, I was wondering if there is a reasonably simple criterion for deciding whether its normal bundle  admits a flat connection. I am not ruling out monodromy in the statement of the question (thus for example, a Moebius strip immersed in $R^3$ fits the bill.)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are asking a purely topological question, right? You're not asking when the standard Euclidean connection on $R^n$, when restricted to the normal bundle, is flat, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is a purely topological question.

Comment: There is some relevant discussion here: http://www.mathkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/research/3130/Flat-metrics-on-manifolds-and-vector-bundles 